# React Native - Failing to build on Android when I add new packages

Tags: react-native, npm-install

I can't seem to find what makes this error occur. Whenever I `npm install` a new package, say for example `react-native-linear-gradient` (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient), I follow the instructions in their readme and I've also replaced the `compile` keyword with `implementation` inside the `dependencies` in the `build.gradle` file.

Now, after I sync the gradle files using Android Studio it succeeds. However, when I build the project, it throws an error during compilation which stops at `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac`.

[image: Error during compilation]

I also execute `react-native link` whenever I install a new package using `npm`. I've also tried creating a new project and it still produces the same error.

Note: This error doesn't occur if I run a react native project without packages and builds perfectly.

EDIT: I also can't run react native projects with or without packages using the terminal command `react-native run-android` because it keeps throwing this error. (see image below)

[image]

Comment: Did you follow these instructions? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started -> Building projects with native code

Comment: @GyuriT yeah but I inserted a step that wasn't supposed to be there :) it was my bad. View my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was letting Android Studio build a freshly initialized React Native project. What I did was I created a new clean project and ran `react-native run-android` first before using Android Studio.